# My Automated Python script loses so much performance over time

Tags: python, performance, while-loop, pyautogui

This is my code, i know its long and messy code, but basically. At start its pretty fast and stuff, but after while you can notice really huge performance jumps, after 6 hours, i came back. and one click of keyboard button took like 10 seconds, can anybody help me find why is it slowing so much.
If you dont understand the code because i know its very messy and no comments. Its basically while loop that runs arround pressings buttons, and when it encounters pokemon, it reads its name and if its the one i want, it notifies me. Or if it errors, it notifies me too.
If i dont want it, it kills it

```py
            while active:

                gc.collect()
                gc.collect()
                gc.collect()

                time.sleep(0.1)


                def waitclick():
                    while True:
                        if keyboard.read_key() == "f6":
                            global active
                            active = False

                thread = threading.Thread(target=waitclick).start()



                im = numpy.asarray(pyautogui.screenshot(region=hpcheck))


                # Define the blue colour we want to find - remember OpenCV uses BGR ordering
                color = [175, 65, 63]
                X, Y = numpy.where(numpy.all(im == color, axis=2))
                x = list(X)
                if lenght:
                    cnt = 0
                    if len(x) <= lenght * (3 / 4):
                        while len(x) <= lenght* (5 / 6):
                            if cnt > 20:
                                pyautogui.click(2119, 793)
                                pyautogui.keyDown('4')
                                time.sleep(0.01)
                                pyautogui.keyUp('4')
                                pyautogui.click(2050, 1120)
                                pyautogui.click(1720, 1030)

                                break
                            cnt += 1
                            time.sleep(1)
                            pyautogui.moveTo(potion[0],potion[1], random.uniform(0.5,1))
                            pyautogui.click(potion[0],potion[1])
                            time.sleep(0.01)
                            pyautogui.click(potion[0],potion[1])
                            time.sleep(0.1)
                            pyautogui.moveTo(mainpoke[0],mainpoke[1],random.uniform(0.5,1))
                            pyautogui.click(mainpoke[0],mainpoke[1])
                            pyautogui.click(mainpoke[0], mainpoke[1])
                            im = Image.fromarray(im)
                            im.save("health.png")
                            im.close()


                            im = numpy.asarray(pyautogui.screenshot(region=(hpcheck)))
                            # Define the blue colour we want to find - remember OpenCV uses BGR ordering
                            color = [175, 65, 63]
                            X, Y = numpy.where(numpy.all(im == color, axis=2))
                            x = list(X)


                        lenght = len(x)
                else:
                    lenght = len(x)





                key = keys[0] if steps % 2 == 0 else keys[1]
                pyautogui.keyDown(key)
                pixels = []
                battle = False
                timeup = False




                def wait():
                    global stepsleft
                    global steps
                    global battle
                    counter = 0
                    for i in range(stepsleft):

                        if battle:
                            break
                        counter += 1
                        time.sleep(onetile-(random.uniform(0.001,0.002)))
                    stepsleft = stepsleft - counter
                    if stepsleft == 0:
                        steps += 1
                        stepsleft = tiles
                    global timeup
                    timeup = True





                thread = threading.Thread(target=wait).start()

                while True:

                    if timeup:

                        break
                    im = numpy.asarray(pyautogui.screenshot(region=(check)))
                    if list(im[0, 0]) == [230, 230, 230]:
                        battle = True

                        break





                pyautogui.keyUp(key)
                stepcount += 1


                im = numpy.asarray(pyautogui.screenshot(region=(check)))

                # im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

                if stepcount > 15:
                    if fails > 100:
                        call = client.calls.create(twiml='<Response><Say>Ahoy, World!</Say></Response>',
                                                   to='+421949847318', from_='+18596961895')
                        payload = {

                            "content": f"Step Fail, continuing."
                        }

                        r = requests.post(f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channel_id}/messages",
                                          data=payload,
                                          headers=header)
                        gc.collect()
                        fails = 0
                        stepfails += 1
                        if stepfails > 10:
                            break
                    pyautogui.click(2119, 793)
                    pyautogui.keyDown('4')
                    time.sleep(0.01)
                    pyautogui.keyUp('4')
                    pyautogui.click(2050,1120)
                    pyautogui.click(1720, 1030)

                    time.sleep(1)
                    fails += 1
                if battle == True:
                    breaks += 1
                    stepcount = 0
                    c = 0
                    e = False
                    while True:
                        if c > 600:
                            e = True
                            break
                        else:
                            im = numpy.asarray(pyautogui.screenshot(region=(namecheck)))

                            if list(im[0, 0]) == [254, 254, 254]:

                                break
                            c += 1

                    if e:
                        pyautogui.keyDown('4')
                        time.sleep(0.01)
                        pyautogui.keyUp('4')
                        pyautogui.click(2050, 1120)
                        time.sleep(1)


                    else:
                        encounters += 1
                        im = numpy.asarray(pyautogui.screenshot(region=(mon)))
                        im = cv2.resize(im, None, fx=1.2, fy=1.2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
                        im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

                        kernel = numpy.ones((1, 1), numpy.uint8)

                        im = cv2.threshold(cv2.bilateralFilter(im, 5, 75, 75), 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
                        im = cv2.dilate(im, kernel, iterations=1)
                        im = cv2.erode(im, kernel, iterations=1)
                        im = ~im
                        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im)

                        text = text.strip().replace("\n","")


                        ime = Image.fromarray(im)
                        ime.save(f"Wild {text}.png")
                        ime.close()

                        if text == "":
                            ime = Image.fromarray(im)
                            ime.save("fail.png")
                            ime.close()
                            im = numpy.asarray(pyautogui.screenshot(region=(mon)))
                            im = cv2.resize(im, None, fx=1.6, fy=1.6, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
                            im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

                            kernel = numpy.ones((1, 1), numpy.uint8)

                            im = cv2.threshold(cv2.bilateralFilter(im, 5, 75, 75), 0, 255,
                                               cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
                            im = cv2.dilate(im, kernel, iterations=1)
                            im = cv2.erode(im, kernel, iterations=1)
                            im = ~im
                            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im).strip()

                            print(">" + text + "<")
                            if text == "":
                                ime = Image.fromarray(im)
                                ime.save("fail2.png")
                                ime.close()
                                im = numpy.asarray(pyautogui.screenshot(region=mon))
                                print(">" + text + "<")
                                im = cv2.resize(im, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
                                im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

                                kernel = numpy.ones((1, 1), numpy.uint8)

                                im = cv2.threshold(cv2.bilateralFilter(im, 5, 75, 75), 0, 255,
                                                   cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
                                im = cv2.dilate(im, kernel, iterations=1)
                                im = cv2.erode(im, kernel, iterations=1)
                                im = ~im
                                text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im).strip()
                                if text == "":

                                    im = numpy.asarray(pyautogui.screenshot(region=check))
                                    if list(im[0, 0]) != [230, 230, 230]:
                                        pass
                                    else:
                                        Image.fromarray(im)
                                        ime.save("fail3.png")

                                        ime.close()
                                        print(">" + text + "<")
                                        payload = {

                                            "content": f"Go look at this bro, i failed again."
                                        }

                                        r = requests.post(f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channel_id}/messages", data=payload,
                                                          headers=header)
                                        active = False
                                        call = client.calls.create(twiml='<Response><Say>Ahoy, World!</Say></Response>',
                                                                   to='+421949847318', from_='+18596961895')
                                        gc.collect()


                                        break
                        if text.replace("[S]","").replace("[E]","").replace("\n","") not in pokemonlist:
                            ime = Image.fromarray(im)
                            ime.save("fail.png")
                            ime.close()
                            im = numpy.asarray(pyautogui.screenshot(region=mon))

                            im = cv2.resize(im, None, fx=1.6, fy=1.6, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
                            im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

                            kernel = numpy.ones((1, 1), numpy.uint8)

                            im = cv2.threshold(cv2.bilateralFilter(im, 5, 75, 75), 0, 255,
                                               cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]


                            im = cv2.dilate(im, kernel, iterations=1)
                            im = cv2.erode(im, kernel, iterations=1)
                            im = ~im
                            text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im).strip().replace("\n","")
                            print(">" + text + "<")
                            if text.replace("[S]","").replace("\n","").replace("[E]","") not in pokemonlist:
                                ime = Image.fromarray(im)
                                ime.save("fail2.png")
                                ime.close()
                                im = numpy.asarray(pyautogui.screenshot(region=mon))
                                im = cv2.resize(im, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
                                im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

                                kernel = numpy.ones((1, 1), numpy.uint8)

                                im = cv2.threshold(cv2.bilateralFilter(im, 5, 75, 75), 0, 255,
                                                   cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
                                im = cv2.dilate(im, kernel, iterations=1)
                                im = cv2.erode(im, kernel, iterations=1)
                                im = ~im
                                text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im).strip()
                                print(">" + text + "<")
                                if text.replace("[S]","").replace("\n","").replace("[E]","") not in pokemonlist:
                                    ime = Image.fromarray(im)
                                    ime.save("fail3.png")
                                    ime.close()
                                    print(">" + text + "<")
                                    payload = {

                                        "content": f"Go look at this bro, i failed again."
                                    }

                                    r = requests.post(f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channel_id}/messages", data=payload,
                                                      headers=header)
                                    active = False
                                    call = client.calls.create(twiml='<Response><Say>Ahoy, World!</Say></Response>',
                                                               to='+421949847318', from_='+18596961895')
                                    gc.collect()


                                    break
                        encounter_time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
                        times.append(encounter_time)

                        if not ram or encounters < 5:
                            ram = process.memory_info().rss
                        if encounters < 15:
                            recentspeed = "None yet"
                        else:
                            recentspeed = str(round(
                                (15 / (encounter_time - times[encounters - 15]).total_seconds()) * 60, 2)) + "/min"
                        print(
                            f"Pokemon: {text} #{encounters}\nSpeed: {round((encounters / (encounter_time - start).total_seconds()) * 60, 2)}/min \nRecent Speed: {recentspeed}\nRam usage is {process.memory_info().rss} Starting usage was {process.memory_info().rss-ram} Garbage is {gc.get_count()}")

                        payload = {
                            "content": f"{'-'*20}\nPokemon: {text} #{encounters}\nSpeed: {round((encounters / (encounter_time - start).total_seconds()) * 60, 2)}/min \nRecent Speed: {recentspeed}\n Ram Change: `{(process.memory_info().rss-ram)//1000000}MB`\nRam usage: `{process.memory_info().rss//1000000}MB`\nStarting usage: `{ram//1000000}MB`\nGarbage: {gc.get_count()}\nCPU: {psutil.cpu_percent()}"
                        }

                        r = requests.post(f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{logs_id}/messages", data=payload,
                                          headers=header)
                        gc.collect()

                        #json
                        with open("encounters.json", "r") as a_file:
                            json_object = json.load(a_file)
                        a_file.close()
                        try:
                            json_object[text] += 1
                        except:
                            json_object[text] = 1
                        with open("encounters.json", "w") as a_file:
                            json.dump(json_object, a_file)
                        a_file.close()
                        c = 0
                        e = False
                        while True:
                            if c > 500:
                                pyautogui.click(2119, 793)
                                pyautogui.keyDown('4')
                                time.sleep(0.01)
                                pyautogui.keyUp('4')
                                pyautogui.click(2050, 1120)
                                pyautogui.click(1720, 1030)
                                time.sleep(1)
                                e = True
                                break
                            im = numpy.asarray(pyautogui.screenshot(region=battlecheck))
                            if list(im[0, 0]) == [240, 211, 92]:
                                break
                            c += 1
                        if e == True:
                            continue
                        if (text.startswith("[S]") if shinies else text.replace("[E]","") in shinywanted) or text.replace("[S]","").replace("[E]","") in wanted:
                            time.sleep(2)
                            end = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
                            done = end - start
                            timed = humanize.naturaldelta(done)

                            print("Done! in " + timed)



                            im = numpy.asarray(pyautogui.screenshot(region=win))
                            ime = Image.fromarray(im)
                            ime.save(f"{text}.png")
                            ime.close()



                            # File
                            files = {
                                "file": (f"{text}.png", open(f"{text}.png", 'rb'))
                                # The picture that we want to send in binary
                            }
                            # Optional message to send with the picture
                            payload = {
                                "content": f"Found {text} in {timed} of searching. It took {encounters} encounters"
                            }
                            active = False
                            r = requests.post(f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channel_id}/messages", data=payload,
                                              headers=header, files=files)
                            gc.collect()
                            call = client.calls.create(twiml='<Response><Say>Ahoy, World!</Say></Response>',to='+421949847318',from_='+18596961895')
                            time.sleep(25)
                            if remote:
                                pyautogui.click(3804, 15)

                            break

                            playsound('ringtone.mp3')

                        elif text.startswith("[E]") or text.replace("[S]","").replace("[E]","") in avoid:
                            run()
                            c = 0
                            while True:
                                if c > 300:
                                    pyautogui.click(2119, 793)
                                    pyautogui.click(1720, 1030)
                                    pyautogui.keyDown('4')
                                    time.sleep(0.01)
                                    pyautogui.keyUp('4')
                                    pyautogui.click(2050, 1120)
                                    time.sleep(1)
                                    break
                                else:

                                    im = numpy.asarray(pyautogui.screenshot(region=check))
                                    if list(im[0, 0]) != [230, 230, 230]:

                                        break
                                    c += 1
                        else:
                            #time.sleep(random.randint(50, 70) / 100)
                            kill(text.replace("[S]","").replace("[E]",""))

                            c = 0
                            time.sleep(1)
                            while True:
                                if c > 750:
                                    pyautogui.click(2119, 793)
                                    pyautogui.click(1720, 1030)
                                    pyautogui.keyDown('4')
                                    time.sleep(0.01)
                                    pyautogui.keyUp('4')
                                    pyautogui.click(2050, 1120)
                                    time.sleep(1)
                                    break
                                else:

                                    im = numpy.asarray(pyautogui.screenshot(region=check))
                                    if list(im[0, 0]) != [230, 230, 230]:
                                        break
                                    c += 1
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Aren't you creating 20 new threads every second?

Comment: JonSG i guess i am but like every 10 seconds, but what should i do

Answer (score 0):

The code is barely legible, split it in functions or classes, and avoid global variables. Chances are you are overflowing the RAM of your computer or something like that, if you are appending information to a variable, remember deleting it after if it grows to much or storing it in a database-like system.

Something similar (or worst) applies to threads if you create too many without deleting them at some point.